# After asking a question

Tags: discussion

Few days after asking a question, if the questioner solves the question in a better way than the answers he had received, what should he do?

Answer (score 6):

Add the better answer.

If there was an answer already accepted, probably unaccept it and accept the new one.

Comment: As a note on the mechanics, if you self-answer and accept your own answer, you do not get the 15 reputation and the answer is also *not* put at the top of the list, like accepted answers usually are.

Comment: @MadScientest That said, if it really is the better answer, votes should put it above the rest anyway in a vote-sort.